# go install creates directory os_arch - select different output directory

Tags: go

I have this folder structure for my `fib` package:

```
$ tree 
.
└── src
    └── fib
        ├── fib
        │   └── main.go
        ├── fib.go
        └── fib_test.go
```

(`main.go` is in package `main`, `fib(_test).go` is in package `fib`)

GOPATH is set to `$PWD/src`, GOBIN is set to `$PWD/bin`. When I run `go install fib/fib`, I get a file called `fib` in the directory `bin` (this is what I expect):

```
$ tree bin/
bin/
└── fib
```

But when I set `GOOS` or `GOARCH`, the directory in the form `GOOS_GOARCH` is created:

```
$ GOARCH=386 GOOS=windows go install fib/fib
$ tree bin/
bin/
└── windows_386
    └── fib.exe
```

This is not what I want. I'd like to have the file `fib.exe` in the `bin` directory, not in the sub directory `bin/windows_386`.

(How) is this possible?

Comment: Too bad I have to accept one of the answers :)  (both were helpful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't seem possible, as illustrated in [issue 6201](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6201).

> `GOARCH` sets the kind of binary to build.
>   You might be cross-compiling: `GOARCH` might be arm.
>   You definitely don't want to run the `arm` tool on an `x86` system.
>   The host system type is `GOHOSTARCH`.
>
> To install the api tool (or any tools) you need to use

```
GOARCH=$(go env GOHOSTARCH) go install .../api
```

> and then plain '`go tool`' will find them.

In any case (`GOARCH` or `GOHOSTARCH`), the `go` command will install in a fixed location that you cannot change.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "I (don't) want" is incompatible with the go tool; the go tool works how it works. You can a) copy the file to where you want it to be after installing it with the go tool or b) compile it yourself, e.g. by invoking 6g manually (here you can specify the output). If you are unhappy with how the go tool works, just switch to a build tool of your liking, e.g. plain old Makefiles. Note that the go tool helps you there too, e.g. by invoking the compiler via `go tool 6g`