# Why does go install creates an executable in bin\windows_386?

Tags: windows, go

Whenever I run `go install relative\path\to\package` it creates the binaries but places them in a folder called `windows_386` in the `$GOPATH\bin` folder. I purposely set `GOARCH` to the value `386`. I'm running go 1.17.1 on Windows 10 Pro edition if this information is relevant.

My theory is that I set `GOARCH` but in a "local" way, the "global" `GOARCH` is still `amd64` and whenever I install packages with `386` architecture, it puts them in this subfolder. I haven't been able to find any literature to confirm my suspicion though and would like some insight.

Comment: I don't recall if or where this is documented, but the behavior seems obvious; the tools aren't going to put a binary for another os+arch in your PATH by default. Are you just looking for a link to some docs that says this?

Comment: Yeah a document would be great. I guess when you spell it out, it is obvious that this is what it does. That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [mentioned in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27188325/6309) that `go install` would respect `GOARCH`

The "[Compile and install packages and dependencies](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)" section do confirm that:

> When module-aware mode is disabled, other packages are installed in the directory `$GOPATH/pkg/$GOOS_$GOARCH`